# Batch File - change directory to sub folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing, cmd

I am writing a bath file i need to move to the subdirectory i prompt user to enter a path that gets stored in

```
 %DialogPath%
```

and i change the path to

```
 CD /D %DialogPath%
```

Now i am check the folder with in this path i have a subfolder named

```
images
```

i wantto go inside this

I am doing

```
IF EXIST images
CD %images%
```

But this does not seem to work the batch file gets automatically closed once it reaches the  CD %images% part.

Comment: Rather than give us your narrative, interspersed with *snippets*, can you not construct a small but *complete* actual batch file which we could run ourselves to see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting your code:

```
IF EXIST images
CD %images%
```

I don't understand why you test whether the directory named 'images' exist but then try to change your directory to the value of the variable called 'images'? Notice the difference:

- `images` -- This is a directory name
- `%images%` - This is the value of the variable called `images`

Shouldn't it just be the following?

```
IF EXIST images CD images
```

Also, note that the `IF` statement and the `CD` command following it should be in the same line. In case, you want to split it into multiple lines for the sake of clarity, it should be done as follows:

```
IF EXIST images (
    CD images
)
```

Comment: I want to go inside the images folder to see if a file exists or not

Comment: @user1926152 Okay. That doesn't change my answer though. If you want to get into the directory named 'images', you should be writing `CD images`, and not `CD %images%`.

Comment: can i check the current working directory once i do CD images